# DB2 ODBC: "HY010 function sequence error" from a query that did not fail

Tags: db2, odbc

I'm looking at an `HY010 Function Sequence Error` on a DB2 `INSERT` query ... and Kibana gives me the actual values that were used in the parameter substitutions!

When I run this query by hand,the query does not fail.  And indeed, it usually doesn't.  (This code has been in service for many years.)  *(I can now confirm that the values which I substituted in my hand-queries match those produced by the underlying code.  "The query would work, if ODBC got that far.")*

Most of the SO and other descriptions of `HY010` on Inserts point to problems with the data values that were used.  But I see no obvious problems with these values (although I'm still looking).  Are there any *other* angles that you might suggest I should try?  All of the values here were provided by parameter substitutions, and my guess is that the ODBC layer is actually having a problem here *before* the query is actually attempted on the host.

I have also carefully researched the Microsoft documentation for `SQLExecute()` concerning `HY010` codes, and none of these seem relevant.

I will ask the DBA's and infrastructure teams to see if the ODBC drivers we are now using are up-to-date.

Comment: IF the symptom recreates on demand, take a CLI trace as described in the Db2 Knowledge Centre. Sometimes things are not what you assume. You can study the text of the formatted trace and see what is really happening. Additionally, you can save a lot of time by simply ensuring that your Db2 driver is the __latest version__ and __latest fixpack__ .

Comment: If the symptom does __not__ recreate on demand, CLI trace is unsuitable. Sometimes HY010 happens after a previous exception, which might not have been correctly handled, and sometimes there may be additional evidence in the diagnostic files of the Db2-server , or sometimes at the client side if you match the timestamps and look at what was happening in the seconds before the HY010 symptom.

Comment: Thank you *very* much, Mao.  This may help to explain why I am having difficulty reproducing this issue in test.  I will ask my trusty DBA to see if we have a fixpack problem.